# Can you please clear my trig doubt?

Tags: trigonometry

[image]

Why are they dividing 90 by 84.81...

It's really confusing. Kindly help me clear my query. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I think there is a typo in the picture. Clearly **DIMENSIONS** (units) are not matching

Comment: So, for those originally confused like me, the notation $94^g23'87''$ refers to an angular measure in terms of [Gradians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradian) where $400$ gradians corresponds to a full circle.  From here, we can see $100^g=90^\circ$ is a convenient conversion from grads to degrees.  We have then that the angle given above is $94^g23'87''=94.2387^g\cdot \frac{90^\circ}{100^g}=84.81483^\circ$.  What confuses me is what comes after and where the final digit of $84.81483\color{red}{4}$ came from in the picture... $0.942387\cdot 90 = 84.81483$ exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$94.2387^g=\frac{90°}{100^g}94.2387^g=84.81483°$$
$$60\cdot0.81483°=48.8898'$$
$$60\cdot0.8898'=53.388''$$

Hence $$84°48'53''$$

Comment: Thank you very much for your precious time. God bless you!